# Asp.Net MVC 4 Default Url - missing trailing slash messes up href links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes

My project is configured to use the project url a.k.a "localhost/AppName/" and no specific page or anything, everything works fine, but if the user removes the last slash, my hrefs stop working because it ignores the "AppName", so for an example, if I've got an action called Books/Index, if the user removes the last slash "localhost/AppName" and hit enter and then clicks on the link to navigate to the books/index, the full path will be "localhost/Books/Index" which will not work, because it is missing the "AppName" after localhost.

I've tried to change the route and create a rewrite rule but still, no luck.. I'm not sure why this happends and that is what worries me, I've considered changing the way the links are generated, but I **think** enforcing the "/" would be better, any thoughts on this will be appreciated.

I'm using the default route by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways trying to fix this, you can google it, quite some solutions there you can try. but none of them perfect.

In my option, the real fix is just to void using the relative path. In your case, you should not use books/index as the href, instead, you should always use the url helper to create the absolute path.

The cause of this problem comes from the asp.net route mechanism, so the root fix is just staying with the route mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had this problem too.. i'm not sure if this is the right solution, but this worked fine for me ! Use @Url.Action() for href..

```
<a href = @Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")>
```